# how to write stored procedure to select a particular column using functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two tables

```
tblSTATUS
   StatusID|PlanID|Description|EmailSubject|EmailFrom|EmailTo||Comment
     1        8    Approved                                aaa
     2        7    Rejected                                bbb
     3        7    Rejected                                ccc
     4        42   Rejected                                ccc

tblSTATUSREASON
     PlanID|REASONS 
       7      failed
       7      not eligible
       42     not eligible
```

when i send email to particular person if their plan is (only) rejected it stores in table `tblstatusreason` the reasons for rejected and PlanID used which is dependent on `tblStatus`.

i should retrieve evrything in grid view C# code using stored procedures and displaying it for user according to description.

Now my problem is i can retrieve and display all the other columns but i dont know how to display rReasons so i want to `select [REASONS] from tblSTATUSREASON` where for that particluar `description = rejected from tblSTATUS` and also i dont want to change my tables/columns.I need sql stored procedure for this particular thing

Answer (score 0):

You need also where

```
select R.PlanID,REASONS
FROM tblSTATUSREASON R
INNER JOIN tblSTATUS S
ON R.PlanID = S.PlanID
AND description = 'rejected'
```

Comment: This won't work as `PlanID` is ambiguous across both tables, you need to use your aliases.  Also you dont need `AND` as you only have a `WHERE` condition.  You need to put WHERE in there.